# trying to have different error through login with two hardcoded logins

Tags: php, if-statement, notepad++

```
if(empty($_POST['mail']) || empty($_POST['password']))
{
    header("Location: login1.php?error4");
}
else
{
    if(($_POST['mail'] == "peter@wijkmanska.se" && $_POST['password'] == "Webbserver") || ($_POST['mail'] == "hej@wijkmanska.se" && $_POST['password'] == "hej123"))
    {
        $login = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(($_POST['mail'] != "peter@wijkmanska.se" && $_POST['password'] != "Webbserver") || ($_POST['mail'] != "hej@wijkmanska.se" && $_POST['password'] != "hej123"))
        {
            header("Location: login1.php?error1");
        }
        else if(($_POST['password'] != "Webbserver" && $_POST['mail'] == "peter@wijkmanska.se") || ($_POST['password'] != "hej123" && $_POST['mail'] == "hej@wijkmanska.se"))
        {
            header("Location: login1.php?error3");
        }
        else if(($_POST['mail'] != "peter@wijkmanska.se" && $_POST['password'] == "Webbserver") || ($_POST['mail'] != "hej@wijkmanska.se" && $_POST['password'] != "hej123"))
        {
            header("Location: login1.php?error2");
        }
        else{
            echo "wrong";
        }
    }
}
```

anyone knows what's wrong with it? it always does error1 unless I put nothing to log in then it gives me error 4 (empty fields gives error 4)

update:

tried var dump cause someone told me (var dump at error1)

```
array (size=2)
  'mail' => string 'asd@a.com' (length=9)
  'password' => string 'Webbserver' (length=10)
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` before the if statement and **update your question** with the result

Comment: Why tagging your question with "notepad++"?

Comment: array (size=2)
  'mail' => string 'asd@a.com' (length=9)
  'password' => string 'Webbserver' (length=10)
@Mehdi Bounya

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your `$_POST['mail']` or `$_POST['password']` is empty. Check it with `var_dump($_POST)`. And the best practice is set `required` to your file in form.

Answer (score 0):

Your test:

```
if(
    (
      $_POST['mail'] != "peter@wijkmanska.se"
      &&
      $_POST['password'] != "Webbserver"
    )
    ||
    (
      $_POST['mail'] != "hej@wijkmanska.se"
      &&
      $_POST['password'] != "hej123"
    )
  )
```

is ALLWAYS true, if you enter `peter@wijkmanska.se` and `Webbserver` the first alternative is TRUE, if you enter `hej@wijkmanska.se` and `hej123`, the second alternative is TRUE but it gives FALSE if you enter `abc@xyz` and `abc123`

Change it into:

```
if(
   !(
      (
        $_POST['mail'] == "peter@wijkmanska.se"
        &&
        $_POST['password'] == "Webbserver"
      )
    ||
      (
        $_POST['mail'] == "hej@wijkmanska.se"
        &&
        $_POST['password'] == "hej123"
      )
    )
  )
```

Same method apply to other tests.